# Обработка видео на Python или С#

Tags: c#, python-3.x, видео

Мне необходимо написать программу, которая сможет в реальном времени формировать видеоряд и отображать его на экране. Будет заранее определённое количество "кусочков" видео и, отдельно - определённое количество аудиофайлов. Программа должна в произвольном режиме склеивать видеофрагменты и накладывать на них аудио. Было бы предпочтительнее сделать эту задачу на языке *Python* или *C#*. Прошу указать, какие языки, библиотеки, возможно, фреймворки нужно использовать для этой задачи. Может, посоветуете курсы/книги по обработке видео с помощью кода?
Я хочу запустить код на удалённой виртуальной машине и "стримить" с неё(например, на том же Ютубе), управляя процессом со своего ПК (для этого напишу клиент с GUI) - это конечная задача.

//Правка: было бы хорошо ещё отображать надписи на видео и накладывать изображения с поддержкой прозрачности поверх видеоряда

Я пока не работал с обработкой видео ни на одном из ЯП, прошу простить за возможную глупость вопроса.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Видео надо обрабатывать не питоном и не шарпом, а видеокартой. То есть системными кодеками. Язык, из которого к ним можно достучаться, совершенно не важен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видео - это наверняка сжатое видео ибо несжатое занимает ооочень много места и его энкодинг занимает ооооочень много времени и ресурсов. Всегда. Монтаж + энкодинг - еще больше.

В твоем случае нет необходимости это делать. В твоем случае достаточно создать видеоплеер с возможностью проигрывания плейлиста и аудиоплеер которые будут работать паралельно.

То есть ты добавляешь в плейлист целый ряд обрезков, перемешиваешь их в случайном порядке. Звук видео - мьютишь.

Кнопка плей - включает видеоряд и музыку одновременно.

Ну и не забыть реализовать отключалку скринсейвера и гаснущего монитора + функционал фуллскрин проигрывания.

---

Ничего общего с обработкой видео, как видишь, здесь нет и в помине. И все предельно просто. А кода будет очень мало.

Comment: И как теперь стримить на ютуб?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov для этого есть внешнее програмное обеспечение, которое может стримить или экран или окно программы. Для чего изобретать велосипед?)